# Probability distribution of $X = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sigma_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j$ where $\xi_k$ i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with $$P(\xi_k=1) = 0.5, \hspace{5mm} P(\xi_k=-1) = 0.5 $$
For $\sigma_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$ fixed real numbers, let $$X = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n \sigma_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j .$$
What is the probability distribution of $X$?

Comment: You should give us more context/motivation/thoughts? Do you expect $X$ to follow some particular distribution? Are you interested is some parameters (mean, variance...)?

Comment: @leonbloy There's no context: I had a pocket of free time in my hands, so I played around in Octave akin to a squirrel in a walnut sack. Here are some preliminary observations: If the subset sums of the set $C=\{\sigma_{ij}:1\leq i<j\leq n\}$ do not overlap, then the probability distribution is uniform on $1-2*C$. Otherwise (e.g. $C=\{1\}$ or $C=\{-1,1\}$) then the distribution seems to vary. For $C=\{1\}$ it seems we get exponential distribution as $n\to\infty$, for $C=\{-1,1\}$ we get Gaussian as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: correction: if the subset sums of $C$ do not overlap, then the distribution is uniform on a subset of $1-2C$. Perhaps it is calculable but not wholly obvious at the first sight which subset it is.

Comment: When $\sigma_{ij}$ are i.i.d. integer valued r.v. with zero mean, or when $\sigma_{ij}$ are i.i.d. Gaussian r.v. with mean zero, it seems the limiting distribution is again Gaussian as $n\to\infty$ (with proper normalization).

Comment: I must admit these observations are as vague as they are not well formulated mathematically. Also, I admit that this is a lazy question, and perhaps a more knowledgeable person can point me to a textbook where I can find the answers to all these.

Comment: Seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441849/quadratic-forms-of-indpendent-random-variables

Comment: @leonbloy this is amazing, more than what I hoped to find. Sir, your arrow just landed on the center of the target. Thank you for response.